# Let $X$ be an irreducible variety, $G$ a finite subgroup of automorphisms of $X$. Then there is an open subset $U \subset X$ where $G$ acts freely.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, group-actions

I'm looking for a reference (or proof), of the following well known fact:

Let $X$ be an irreducible variety, $G$ a finite subgroup of automorphisms of $X$. Then there is an open subset $U \subset X$ where $G$ acts freely.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 2):

For $1\neq g\in G$, the set
$$Z_g=\{x\in X\mid gx=x\}$$
is Zariski closed (It is the inverse of the diagonal by the map $(\mathrm{id},g)\colon X\mapsto X\times X$).
Then, $\cup_g Z_g$ is Zariski closed and $G$ acts freely over its complement.